# Convert integer to be used in strcat

Tags: c, casting, char, strcat

I'm trying to open different files by having a for loop increment a counter, then appending that counter to the filename to be opened, but I'm stuck on how to use strcat to do this. If I understand right, strcat takes 2 strings, but my counter is an int. How can I make it so that it becomes a string?

```
for(a = 1; a < 58; a++) {
    FILE* inFile;
    int i;

    char filename[81];

    strcpy(filename, "./speeches/speech");
    strcat(filename, a);
    strcat(filename, ".txt");
```

Definitely doesn't work since a is an int. When I try casting it to char, because a starts at 1 and goes to 57, I get all the wrong values since a char at 1 is not actually the number 1.. I'm stuck.

Comment: Sorry for my previous answer, just realized it's C and not C++..

Comment: strcat(filename,itoa(a));

Comment: @michaeltang itoa() is not a standard function, so you need to be careful using it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't cast an integer into a string, that's just not possible in C.

You need to use an explicit formatting function to construct the string from the integer. My favorite is [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Once you realize that, you can just as well format the entire filename in a single call, and do away with the need to use `strcat()` (which is rather bad, performance-wise) at all:

```
snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "./speeches/speech%d", a);
```

will create a string in `filename` constructed from appending the decimal representation of the integer `a` to the string. Just as with `printf()`, the `%d` in the formatting string tells `snprintf()` where the number is to  be inserted. You can use e.g. `%03d` to get zero-padded three-digits formatting, and so on. It's very powerful.

Comment: Wow, you're fast, haha. Thanks for the tip!! snprintf does seem more efficient than trying to build a string with strcpy and strcat. This was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use a single statement for this,

```
snprintf(filename,sizeof(filename),"./speeches/speech%d.txt",a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are right about the strcat function. It only works with strings.

You could use the ['sprintf'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) function. A modification to your code below:

```
char append[2]; //New variable
for(a = 1; a < 58; a++) {
  FILE* inFile;
  int i;

  char filename[81];

  strcpy(filename, "./speeches/speech");
  sprintf(append,"%d",a); // put the int into a string
  strcat(filename, append); // modified to append string
  strcat(filename, ".txt");
```

Comment: I would also recommend moving the `char filename[81]` outside the loop and just keep clearing the filename after the end of the loop.